# how can I clearly differentiate between AWS EC2 AMI, snapshot and instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm super confused about what AMI, snapshot, and instance are. also, the aws documentation did not clear anything to me. I still do not understand what they are and the difference between them

Could somebody clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Instance** : is the virtual machine ( computing resource ) ; named EC2 in AWS terminology .
- **Snapshot** : is a backup of volume (virtual hard-disk , named EBS) that can be associated with the instance (with the virtual machine ).
- **AMI** : is a **special snapshot** , it is a snapshot for the **root** volume ( where the OS is installed). That's why you can boot new instance (machine virtual) from that AMI since it is a snapshot of root volume ( includes OS) .
- **OS** : Operating System .

Comment: In real life then, Instance would be a physical computer (PC) which has hard disk and SSD. Snapshot would basically be a copy of either hard disk or SSD? AMI can be a snapshot ONLY of a volume that is used to boot the OS?

Comment: exactly   

Comment: can you provide any example how some real company would use EC2?

Comment: Sure ! I am managing AWS account of our company where we provisioned more than 40 EC2 instances between Dev environment and production environment. We use an EC2 instance  to deploy our web applications, RestFull API. ... so on; we installed dependencies (`sudo apt-get install apache` or `yum install httpd` for example )  then, we deploy the application on that EC2. You might need an ELB ( loadbalancer ) to manage the traffic among multiple EC2 if you require a high scalable/available deployment.

Comment: This answer somewhat mischaracterizes an AMI.  It is not technically a snapshot.  It is a container with some metadata and references to one or more snapshots taken from an existing instance, having a snapshot of *at least* the boot volume, and sometimes additional volumes.  When you create an AMI, the associated snapshots are created automatically.  You create AMIs from running instances, and you create instances from AMIs.

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a repository containing the information required for you to launch a virtual machine on AWS including the operating system, OS instantiation instructions, etc.

An instance is a running instance of a virtual machine, that is created from the AMI. To create a new instance you select an AMI (e.g. Ubuntu, CentOS, Windows etc.) and *instantiate* it - i.e. you ask the AWS infrastructure to read the information contained in the AMI and use that to create a running virtual machine, which is the instance.

A snapshot is just that - a copy of the EBS disks that the AWS infrastructure saves on request to a file.

HTH.